# jQuery validation code for all checkboxes on a form

Tags: jquery, message, validation, checkbox

I have a Form that generates a list of records with a checkbox for each record next to it.

If the user does not check any of the records and hits submit, then a dialog box should warn him saying "you did not check any records".  If he chooses to continue, then he will be redirected to the next page, otherwise he will be held on the same page to select the rest of the records.

I am not so good with jQuery and javascript.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The logic i am looking for is something like this

on submit button

```
<script>
if(
 (input:checkbox).count = (input:checkbox).is(checked).count
 //proceed to the next page
else(
 dialogue("Message")
)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery this will be:

```
    

     $(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(){

            if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){

                // next

            }else{

                alert('check a box');

            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

first, let's assume your form has id="myForm":

```
$('#myForm').submit(function()
{
    if($('#myForm input:checkbox:checked').length == 0)
    {
        //Tell the user he/she needs to check some boxes
        return false; // this stops the form from being submitted
    } 
});
```

EDIT: Remember to put all of this inside

```
$('document').ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: This is probably overkill but to be a bit more careful you may want to consider selecting just checkboxes inside the particular form you're trying to submit.  `($('#myForm input:checkbox:checked').length == 0)`  Furthermore, if you have sections of checkboxes within a form you may want to decorate them with their own class and use that as well.  `($('#myForm .favouriteBooks input:checkbox:checked').length == 0)`

Comment: good catch on only selecting checkboxes inside the Form. Regarding your other suggestion, it's a good one, but kinda overkill in the scope of the question.

Comment: Agreed but I felt it was worth mentioning :)

Comment: @Atheist Thank you  for your input i could have a start with your support